# ExpressJS breaking when trying to serve missing images

Tags: node.js, express

**ExpressJS Newbie Warning**

I have a simple server running with expressjs and all works well when all images are present. But if an image is missing expressjs stops with the following error

```
(node:5793) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module 'jpg'
```

This is preventing anything else from loading, or even an links working. The page just hangs there. Shouldn't it simple not serve the image (send a 404) and still allow the site to work?

**UPDATE**

```
router.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    dynamicStatic.setPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/templates/' + 
    app.get('templatePath')));
    res.render('index');
});
```

I use dynamicStatic because I need to be able to set the path dynamically based on some conditions. This sets express.static under the hood. I don't think that has anything to do with it because other images are being served fine. Of course I could be wrong, though.

**UPDATE 2**
The images remain in a (pending) state which is where the hang up is coming from.

[image]

This image shows the error messages I receive in Node/Express. 
[image]

Comment: Could you show your code ?

Comment: Shouldn't it simple not serve the image (send a 404) and still allow the site to work? Yes. :)

Comment: @Atef added some a code snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

I think catching the exception with a `try {} catch` block should do the job just fine.

Put the code that could throw an exception in the `try` block and if an exception is thrown send the 404 status.

Here’s a try:

```
router.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
   try {
         dynamicStatic.setPath(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/templates/' + 
         app.get('templatePath')));
         res.render('index');
     } catch(err) {
         res.sendStatus(404);
      }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it's wasn't this simple. I updated this ticket above with some images. For some reason the images remain in a (pending) state.

Comment: @selanac82 Do those image files (1.jpg, 2.jpg, ....) actually exists on your server ?

Comment: i'm running a local server. The first image is of my chrome dev tools and the second is of the error message i receive in webstorm when running the server in debug mode.

Comment: No I’m asking about the images that you are requesting, (1.jpg etc...)

Comment: haha sorry, it's early here. no they aren't on the server. They are missing, but my assumption was, even if they are missing, then they should just return with a 404 meaning they don't exist.

Comment: Could you explain your code a little more ? what's the `app` object in the `app.get('templatePath')` ?

Comment: so app.get('templatePath') will return whatever the current template being used is. It returns from the database. As an example, in my current cast it's returning template2. Which means everything should be served from public/templates/template2. This is working great for all images that are present on the server, but not for ones missing

Comment: also, the app object is the express object. as in, 
const express = require('express');
const app = express();